# DC motor remote control with one push

Tags: motor, dc, linear, actuator, remote

I am planning to use 2 actuators as a gate opener. The linear actuators are hooked to a DC motor controller, with remote, so I  can open/close the gate by either press and hold one of the two buttons on the remote.

I want the remote to act like a push and release button, or at least one push to start, and a second push to stop. I also hope the actuators would stop at a predetermined stop (not allowing them to over-extend.)

I think some sort of relay could be applicable, but I just don't know enough.

Comment: You "hope"? Don't hope; design it that way.

Comment: This is quite a bit short of being specifically answerable.  But a decent remote control has an MCU in the receiver to detect a digital code, and that can run a motor until task completion or safety fault...

Comment: Don't request help for an unspecified problem; ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the control board and remote from any typical garage door opener. The single button on the remote follows your needed logic. Push the button once to start opening. Push again to stop and reverse the movement. The control board actuates a reversing motor using relays. You can start modifying the relay logic to give you what you want. Do a test bench setup while you experiment, then install it on site. Those units use an internal pressure activated limit switch to sense obstructions and end of travel.